# How to save commit message after change on window

Tags: git, commit

After I pushed the code on Github, I realized that I had made a missing commit, so I wanted to modify it
but after I have modified it I don't know how to save it and get out and push the commit again, can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the question, but to help you in your google search: you might be looking for `git amend`. It doesn't really matter that you're using github, that's just a website that holds git repositories. The tool (`git`) is what matters.

Comment: Does [that](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/save-file-in-vi-vim-linux-apple-macos-unix-bsd/) answer your question? (I think you are looking, how to use vi or vim?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you wanted to modify an existing commit by running `git commit --amend`. When you do this, Git lets you modify the commit message in a text editor. Your screenshot shows `nano` or `pico`, a text editor for Linux. You can see the available hotkeys at the bottom of the screen. Press `ctrl-O` to save and then `ctrl-X` to exit.

Because you modified an existing commit, your local Git client will have a different commit than GitHub does. Run `git push --force` to overwrite the old commit on GitHub with the new one you just created. Please note that you should only do this on your own Git branch, not on branches that are shared with others, like for example the `master` branch.